# mixing transactional context (cdi and ejb)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I am new to CDI and EJB and I know that when executing a JPA query in a EJB you have the wildfly transaction context since its container managed around every method providing rollbacks in case of errors but in CDI you don't.

Now my question is what if a EJB is injecting/consuming a request scoped CDI bean as example and that CDI bean executes a JPA query inside an EJB method? Does the CDI query have transaction context (tx management) since its executed in an EJB method?

Comment: why is this a bad question?

Comment: Probably because it's too trivial and Stackoverflow doesn't accept "yes" or "no" as an answer.

Comment: If I had to guess, the usage of "thingy" may be getting you some down votes as well.  To give a bit of an answer on this - if your EJB starts a transaction, it will propagate to your CDI bean.  If your CDI bean is annotated `@Transactional` then it will also start a transaction if one isn't already started.

Comment: This is excellent question, see the John's answer and next time use "transaction manager" instead of "thingy" :-)

Comment: thanks guys, please give me an answer and i ll accept it. i used thingy because i dont know is it manager or context or sope or holder or something :)